# Deleting User's foreign key constraints from 3 tables with one script using postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

I have 3 tables: Users, Orders, Biddings.
I'm trying to delete a user by id but can't because it has foreign key constraints (Orders and Biddings) which I have to remove first. Deleting an order by userId is easy enough, but I can't wrap my head around deleting all biddings + orders with a given user id. There is a direct relation: Users.id = Orders.userId, Order.orderId = Biddings.orderId.
I'm trying to think of a SQL script that will take a user id and delete the User with all his Orders and Biddings. How can that be achieved?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out `ON DELETE CASCADE` foreign keys.

Comment: BTW, are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: @jarlh postgres

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK

Answer (score 1):

have you specified a cascade delete on every Foreign Key constraint? if not i would suggest you create your orders / biddings table with a Foreign Key constraint like that: `FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES users (userID) ON DELETE CASCADE` and `FOREIGN KEY (orderID) REFERENCES orders (orderID) ON DELETE CASCADE`. After that you can simply `delete from users where userID = <ID>`. NOTE that this was the syntax for MySQL, for PostgreSQL it might vary.

Postgres: `userID integer REFERENCES users (userID) ON DELETE CASCADE` inside the attribute definition.

Comment: The tables are already built. Any idea how to do it in the current situation?

Comment: you can still alter the table `ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT users_fk FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES users (userID) ON DELETE CASCADE;` but make sure you drop the old foreign key before doing that

Comment: Thanks, but isn't a script possible? At least to delete all bids made by a user? (As I said, I don't have userId in Bids Table, but it's connected via the Orders table.

Comment: i think a script is no longer needed since you should apply the `ON DELETE CASCADE` also on the foreign key that refers to the orderID in the Bids Table. The scenario would look like that after you delete an user: All orders that are in combination with the removed userID will be deleted and that will also apply on the Bids, since the refering orderID doesn't exist anymore.